# Django - How to filter and return data by groups

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model which I want to return group by an attribute of the object itself. Let's suppose the model is the next one:

```
class User():
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    group = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Later in the view, I would be getting by group all the users:

```
group1 = User.objects.filter(group='1')
group2 = User.objects.filter(group='2')
group3 = User.objects.filter(group='3')
```

But that would return for each group the next structure:

```
[{"username":"user1", "group":"1"}]
[{"username":"user2", "group":"2"}]
[{"username":"user3", "group":"3"}]
```

How can I obtain the next structure (where the group is the root) directly from the filter or how can I combine the groups to achieve that:

```
[
"1": [{"username":"user1","group":"1"}], 
"2": [{"username":"user2","group":"2"}], 
"3": [{"username":"user3","group":"3"}]
]
```

Comment: Do you want to do this with serializers or are you just looking to construct this dict/JSON yourself?

Comment: I would like to learn both approaches

Comment: FYI, your desired output is not valid, it's a list with dict keys. Do you want a dict?

Comment: I need the output to be separated by groups, I don't really catch what you mean, but if the output is by groups, that would be awesome!

Comment: Did you find a solution with serializers? @IainShelvington

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't have a Group model, just a field in the User model. I am not a Django pro, so I don't know of any Django tricks which could help you to get to your goal - though I am certain Django ORM has some functions which will perform a GROUP BY query for you. But why don't you write a completely pythonesque solution, simply transforming the collection you already have into one you want?

**update following the comment**

try something like this script:

```
from functools import reduce

users = [
    {'username': 'foo', 'group':'1'},
    {'username': 'bar', 'group':'2'},
    {'username': 'baz', 'group':'1'},
    {'username': 'asd', 'group':'2'},
    {'username': 'zxc', 'group':'3'},
    {'username': 'rty', 'group':'1'},
    {'username': 'fgh', 'group':'2'},
    {'username': 'vbn', 'group':'3'},
]

def reducer(acc,el):
    group = el['group']
    if not acc.get(group):
        acc[group]=[el.get('username')]
    else:
        acc[group].append(el['username'])
    return acc

print(reduce(reducer, users, {}))
```

It will print the result, which looks close to what you want:

```
{'1': ['foo', 'baz', 'rty'],
 '3': ['zxc', 'vbn', 'vbn'],
 '2': ['bar', 'asd', 'fgh']}
```

Comment: That is where I'm lost, I want to find a pythonic way to transform the data or find a way to achieve that thru the ORM

Comment: ah. well I updated the answer with a possible way to go; it assumes you have a collection of user objects which are dicts with keys of 'username' and 'group', which is probably not far from truth... if they're model objects, you extract values accordingly